# Register and login with password_hash password default

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to improve my security by using password_hash and PDO prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection. I already worked with MySQLi OOP and Procedural. I am trying to shift to PDO and want to learn.
So I created a signup form using PDO which is already working and the encryption of password is working too. But when I logged in even with the correct username and password I can't login.

This is the code I use to hash my password in the sign up form.

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Then I execute it using prepared statements. So no errors at here everything works fine.

But when I tried to login it won't redirect me to the landing page where it should be.

So here is the code to my login

```
<?php  
 session_start();  
 $host = "localhost";  
 $username = "root";  
 $password = "";  
 $database = "PDOtesting";  
 $message = "";  
 try  
 {  
      $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
      $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
      if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
      {  
           if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
           {  
                $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";  
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],  
                          'password'     =>     $_POST["password"]  
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];  
                     header("location:login_success.php");  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>';  
                }  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 catch(PDOException $error)  
 {  
      $message = $error->getMessage();  
 }  
 ?>
```

Should I include also the `password_hash` function that I included it in the signup and where should I place the code?

Comment: Query user by username only; get the result of your query & compare it using `password_verify` function if it works let it's a success otherwise it's not... `password_hash` generate different password for the same string each time you use it as it generate random salt each time it's being used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try and match the password in the query, select the user, return and then use [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) on the result.

Update:

```
<?php  
 ...
 try  
 {  
      $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
      $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
      if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
      {  
           if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
           {  
                $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1";  
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     $_POST["username"]
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                    $result = $statement->fetch();

                    //check password
                    if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $result['password'])) {
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
                        exit(header("location:login_success.php"));
                    } else {
                        $message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>'; 
                    } 
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>';  
                }  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 catch(PDOException $error)  
 {  
      $message = $error->getMessage();  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: like these? password_varify($_POST["password"],PASSWORD_DEFAULT) correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Na `password_varify($_POST["password"], $result->password)`, `$result->password` being the stored hash in the db.

Comment: it won't work for me can you post it just like the query in the code? Sorry for the disturbance :(

Comment: I caught a major error here.  It's password_verify not password_varify. This would throw fatal error

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried everything clearly. But everytime I logged in it already said localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 and when I check the serve logs I got no error.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the function name, which would cause your 500 :(

Comment: oh its okay. Awesome! It worked. Appreciated it so much! Btw can I ask one last question? What is the function of exit before the header? Something like that will end or terminate the script? Thankyousomuch!

Comment: np, I added it because code will continue to execute after setting a header.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I did to signup, I am using `meekrodb` class:

```php
session_start();
include "../includes/db.class.php";

if (!empty($_POST))

    $username =$_POST["username"];
    $pass =$_POST["password"];
    $email =$_POST["email"];
    $id_number =$_POST["id_number"];


    $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $check = DB::query("SELECT * FROM tbs.credentials WHERE username=%s AND email=%s AND id_number=%s", $username, $email, $id_number);


    if ($check)
    {
        echo '
            <div class="medium medium-small red-text animated wobble">Account already exist</div>
            <script> M.toast({html: \'Account already exists\'})</script>
            <p class="medium medium-small teal-text"><a href="../auth/forgot">Click here to reset password</a></p>

        ';
    } else {
        $rows = array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'password'=>$password,
            'email'=>$email,
            'id_number'=>$id_number,
        );
        $validate = DB::insert('credentials', $rows);
        if($validate) {
            echo
                '
                    <div class="medium medium-small green-text animated rubberBand">Account created</div>
                    <script> M.toast({html: \'Account created successful\'})</script>
            ';
        }
    }
}
```

**For Loging in:**

```php
session_start();
include "../includes/db.class.php";

if (!empty([$_POST])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $check = DB::query("SELECT * FROM tbs.credentials where username=%s", $username);

    if ($check)
    {
        $check_password= DB::query("SELECT password FROM tbs.credentials WHERE password=%s", $username);

        if ($check_password){
            password_verify($password, $check_password);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $password;
            echo "Login";
        }
    }
}
```